# How to search for list of elements via LINQ Lambda query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to LINQ and Entity framweork and I am stuck at one place.So, I have 2 table with one to many relationship. Let's say college and students.

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int ParentId {get;set;}  
    public ICollection<College> Colleges { get; set; }
}

public class College
{
    [Key]
    public int CollegeId { get; set; }
    public bool AdmissionStatus { get; set; }
     public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

**Requirement:**

Step 1: I will get `one parent ID (from UI)`, I need to find all the Student with that `parentID` from `Students` table.

Step 2: Now I will get list of Students or StudentsId for a particular parent, and now I want to query that list on students in the `college table` and `find all the students whose status AdmissionStatus is "True"`.

P.S:

1. College can only set two status Accept = true or Reject = false.
2. Once a student status is accepted then No college can make the Status as "Accepted".
3. So, Many college can keep on rejecting a candidate, But once a college accepts the status. Then no college will be able to either reject or accept. Basically that student will not be visible for any college.

I am not sure how to achieve this.

```
  public ActionResult Show()
        {
            var parentId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var StudentList = _context.Students.Where(r => r.ParentId == parentId).ToList();
            // now I want to query the College table now, but I am not sure how to achieve it.
            return View();
        }
```

Each StudentId from the studentlist will be present many times in College table. 
I just want those ones which are accepted or AdmissionStatus = true. Please guide me.

Above mentioned situation is hypothetical, bear with me.

Comment: you want get the list of colleges for which one's son/daughter is accepted? It's not clear what you want from the question

Comment: No, I want to get list of students, whose application status is "accepted" and they are belonging to same parentId

Comment: That is why I get the list of StudentId for a particular parent. And now I want to check for those only

Comment: neither of your objects has a "application status" property

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I meant "AdmissionStaus".

Comment: since AdmissionStatus is on the college object it makes no sense to talk about 'the students AdmissionStatus' there is no such thing

Comment: @Ewan: Sir, I fixed the typo.

Comment: Why is `AdmissionStatus` a property of `College`? Shouldn't student have a `List<College>` property since he applies to many of them?

Comment: either the model or the explaination of the requirement is wrong

Comment: @Ewan: I am really sorry. I fixed it now.

Comment: @adiga: I am really sorry. I fixed it now.

Comment: So, I want to get list of students for a parentId. And now I want to query the college table with that list and side by side I want to get only those results whose status is "ACCEPTED"

Comment: @Ewan: I will clarify myself again. If I am not clear.

Comment: @Unbreakable I'm not sure if I understand correctly but try: `context.Student.Where(s => s.ParentId == parentId) &&(s.Colleges.Any(c => c.AdmissionStatus)))`. This will return all the students for a parent who have been accpeted by atleast one college

Comment: @adiga: Ok, I have a parent Id of 2. Now that parent has 5 students, 2A, 2B, 2C, 2D, 2E. Because of one to many. these all 5 Id's will be present multiple times in College table. I want only the one which has status as accepted.

Comment: @adiga: I will try your query. :)

Comment: @adiga: 2A - accepted, 2A - rejected, 2B rejected, 2D rejected, 2E rejected. So I should get the count as  one, because only 2A got accepted

Comment: @Unbreakable: do you want Students? or Count? or Colleges?

Comment: @adiga: Honestly, I want the count. But I think I can add `.count()` in the end, if I can get the correct LINQ Query. But were you able to understand my requirement, of what I wanted?I will try to rewrite the entire question, and will try to explain myself

Comment: @adiga: I am trying the query you have added. I think I need to put the opening bracket `(` after  `=>` sign right?

Comment: @Unbreakable yes. Or remove the one after parentId. Replace `Where` with `Count` and you'll get he all the students for a parent, who have been admitted to atlease one college

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153629/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-adiga).

Comment: @Unbreakable your mapping still doesn't make sense to me. `College` should have properties related to the college like name, address etc and not `AdmissionStatus`. I think you need to have a `Mapping class` which will contain `CollegeId`, `StudentId` and `AdmissionStatus`. Then Student class will have a list of `StudentCollegeMap`. College class will also have a list of `StudentCollegeMap`

Comment: Agreeing to many comments here:

1 - `AdmissionStatus` should very likely be a `Students` property instead of a `College` one. The element having its status altered or not is the Student, not the College.

2 - Also, if this Model has any resemblance to reality, multiple Colleges can accept the same Student, afaik. Regardless of which one the Student chooses, he still needs to be able to accept any one College that accepted him. So the relationship should be many to many, Student having a foreign key from College or not and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

OK first of all fix your model.

A Parent has many Students, each of whom applies to many colleges

```
Parent
{
    public List<Student> Students
}

Student
{
    public List<Application>() Applications
}

Application
{
    public bool Accepted
}
```

now your linq is simple

```
var acceptedChildernOfParent = db.Parents
    .FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Id = parentID) //get the parent in question
    .Students //look at their childern who are students
    .Where(
        s=>s.Application.Any(a=>a.Accepted == true) //only show those with an accepted applcation
    );
```

Of course EF will make a total hash of the sql. you are better off doing

```
db.Students.SqlQuery(@"
select 
    s.* 
from parents p
left join
   students s 
on
   s.parentId = p.id

left join 
   applications a
on
   a.studentId = s.id

where 
   p.id = @p0
and
   a.Accepted == true"
, parentID);
```

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me. I will try this solution and I will update/comment/accept the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can easiliy combine the two conditions in one query:

```
var StudentList = _context.colleges.Where(r => (r.Student.ParentId == parentId)&&(r.AdmissionStatus)).Select(r => r.Student)).ToList();
```

Comment: I am really sorry, that `Admission status` column is in college table. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var StudentList = _context.Students.Where(r => r.ParentId == parentId && r.Colleges.Any(c => c.AdmissionStatus == true)).ToList();
```